# Given times for athletes to jump is normally distributed, mean = 4, standard deviation = 0.5, what is the sampling distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, sampling, sampling-theory

"A sample of 16 athletes are selected. What is the sampling distribution? Explain clearly and find the mean time and standard deviation"

How do I go about answering this question?

I know that the mean time will be equal to the population mean (4) and that I can calculate the standard error by dividing 0.5 by radical n (here equal to 4). But what do they mean by "what is the sampling distribution?"
"